# Авторизация по email

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь разобраться как реализовать авторизацию по email в Django 1.9 с учетом того, что имею кастомную модель, юзера унаследованную от `AbstractUser`.

Благодаря советам форумчан, c djbook, я добавил в модель юзера строки:

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

Вне класса написал:

```
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

Я правильно понял, что строка, написанная ниже, говорит, что поле `username` должно быть почтой?

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Ну, и поскольку я указал, что это поле обязательно для заполнения, то в процессе регистрации я должен из поля формы под именем `email` положить данные в `user.username`? Но в таком случае, когда почта не уникальна, вместо красивой ошибки об этом, я получаю ругань в виде:

> Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'"

Помогите осилить и разобраться пожалуйста!

Вот код регистрации:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User()
        company = Company()
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.username = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.role = 'boss'
            company.name = user.last_name + " " + user.first_name
            company.creator = user.first_name + " " + user.last_name
            company.save()
            user.company = company
            user.save()
            return redirect('/good_luck/')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

Вот код формы для регистрации:

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    first_name = CharField(label='Имя', max_length=130, required=True)
    last_name = CharField(label='Фамилия', max_length=130, required=True)
    email = EmailField(label='Почта', max_length='130', required=True)
    password = CharField(label='Пароль', required=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Я в этом случае поступаю следующим образом:

Делаю кастомный `Authentication backend`:

```
class EmailAuthBackend(object):

    @staticmethod
    def authenticate(email=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        if not user.check_password(password):
            return None

        return user

    @staticmethod
    def get_user(user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Кастомный бэкенд должен реализовывать как минимум два метода: `authenticate`, который возвращает объект `user`, если авторизация успешна, либо – `None` в противном случае; и метод `get_user`, который принимает `user_id` и возвращает объект `user`, если пользователь существует, либо `None`.

Этот бэкенд подключается в `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'путь_к_модулю.EmailAuthBackend'    
]
```

Затем авторизуете пользователя:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

user = authenticate(email=email,password=password)

if user is None:
    # Пользователь с таким имейлом и паролем не найден.

# Если всё хорошо, логиним пользователя
login(request, user)
return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

По-моему, это самый простой способ.